# ajax call to a php page but php code is ignored

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page where the contents are loaded by an ajax call to the respective PHP page. Here is my javascript that is used to load the page contents into my page container:

```
function loadPage(filename,id){
    var ajaxRequest;
    try{ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();} catch (e){try{ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");} catch (e) {try{ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} catch (e){alert("Error: Browser/Settings conflict");return false;}}}
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET",filename,true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

I have a onload event in my body tag to load the required page (by default my $page variable will load the first page)

```
<body onload="loadPage('getpage.php?page=<?php echo $page; ?>','page_contents');">
```

Everything works fine until I try placing any PHP in those page files. I have buttons for my other pages that load correctly. The php files which my ajax is calling are not rendering any php within `<?php ?>` tags, no errors are given it's simply ignored. When I store pure HTML in those php files everything gets displayed. I even tried to place a include(); on a file that does not exist to see if any errors appear - which does not show. I also tried issuing an exit() at the top of my pages and they are still getting displayed.

Any ideas why my php syntax is getting ignored?

This is on a Windows 2K3 Web edition using IIS 6 and PHP 4.

UPDATE:

I see the code is getting enclosed in HTML comments. When I view the page directly (not using ajax) the PHP is rendered normally. This problem is only happening on my ajax call.

Comment: Are you SURE, that the PHP gets ignored? You do know, that the PHP will only have 'effect', when you're 'echoing' something, right?

Comment: Absolutely! I am quite experienced with php webpages. For example, if I do: `<?php exit(); ?> <HTML HERE>` the HTML is still displayed. or if I replace a string of words in the HTML with <?php echo "Some Text"; ?> that "Some Text" is no where to be found.

Comment: If you do 'view source", is the PHP code displayed? The `<?php ?>` may be hidden from view, but still returned from the server. If so, then the php isn't being parsed on the server - it's a server set up issue.

Comment: It apepars it's returning the php code in html comments `<!--?php ?-->`. Any clue why it would get commented out? could it be related to my ajax request type? I have other ajax calls for different pages on the same webserver which successfully renders the php syntax.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was echoing the file contents with file_get_contents. I completely forgot that I was using this method over include.